# How to stop the autoincrement for id in sails.js

Tags: node.js, sails.js

```
//Controller
  afterCreate: function(datas, cb) {
console.log("Data Id : ",datas.id);//Id:90150
var menudetails = { id : datas.id };//Id:90150
    MenuDetail.create(menudetails).exec(function createMD(err, created){
      console.log("MenuDetail",created);
      console.log("MenuDetail Id : ",created.id);//Id:90103
      if(err) return cb(err);

    });
cb();
```

}

- Here I'm trying to create the new record in MenuDetail with specific id, but it don't create the record for that specified id, it will generate the id which is autoincremented by previous id.
- I need the record with specified id which is given as paramater.

Comment: can you add the model code?

Comment: Thanks for your response Ofer Herman. Now my code is working fine, the problem was due to one lifecyclecallback. In that I have modified the code, after that the logic was working fine.

Answer (score 2):

An easy way to do this is to overwrite the `id` attribute on your model like so:

```
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    id: {
      type: 'integer',
      autoIncrement: false,
      unique: true,
      primaryKey: true
    }
  }
}
```

Doing so will require you to set the id on each record you create.